# JFrame/JPanel drawing from other class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am developing a simple game in java. While this might be a silly question I really do need some help. My game is going to feature multiple levels. I would like to be able to load each level from a new class file to make it more manageable. If this is not a stable solution please tell.

Now my question is this. If my JPanel is in class file A how can I draw to it from class file B? Imagine class file B is my level and so I would have class file C, D, E and so on, all different levels which I want to be able to draw to class file A which holds my JPanel to. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions are:

Pass the class file to the `JPanel`, so for example:

```
JPanel j = new JPanel();
Level l1 = new Level(1);
Level l2 = new Level(2);
j.initlevel(l1);
//wait until level 1 is done
j.initlevel(l2);
```

And have initlevel do the loading:

```
public void initlevel(Level l){
    // for all level parts, load them into "this"
}
```

Or you can make certain properties of the `JPanel` public, and pass it to the level:

```
JPanel j = new JPanel();
new Level(1, j);
//wait until level 1 is done
new Level(2, j);
```

And make the constructor of Level:

```
public Level(int level, JPanel j){
    //for all level parts load them into "j"
}
```

Note that this is a very basic structure, if your game gets a bit more complex you might want to consider reading into Model-View-Controller patterns.

Comment: Also perhaps consider making the level classes extend `JPanel` so you can just override their draw methods.

Comment: `JPanel` doesn't hade a `draw` method, you're probably referring to the `paint()` method. you'd then replace your current `JPanel` with a `LevelPanel` or something like that

Comment: Yep, I specifically meant `paintComponent()`

Answer (score 2):

An ideal design keeps the UI drawing away from the game logic so you are on the right track. 
An example of one such solution could be a class which composes a JPanel which gets notified when the level is changed.
For instance

```
public class LevelViewController implements LevelChangedListener {
   private JPanel viewPane;

   public LevelViewController(JPanel viewPane) {
      this.viewPane = viewPane;
   }

   public void levelChanged(Level level) {
      // Update JPanel with logic now the level has changed
      ...
   }
}

public interface LevelChangedListener {
     void levelChanged(Level level);
}
```

Whatever knows that the player is to advance to the next level will then need to notify its collection of LevelChangedListeners (of which your LevelViewController is one) which will in turn update your JPanel. You could hook other LevelChangedListeners in then as well if you wanted other things to update now that the level has changed.